# importing images doesn't work properly in react + parcel + typescript + module esnext

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parceljs, react-loadable

## Reproductive example repo

[module_esnext_import_image](https://github.com/github0013/module_esnext_import_image)

## How to reproduce

```
git clone https://github.com/github0013/module_esnext_import_image.git
cd module_esnext_import_image
yarn
yarn run src/index.html
```

then, look inside the `dist` folder.  You should see something like `src.7753e686.png` instead of `1.some-random-id.png` (a file name starts with `1`).

[image: src.7753e686.png]

Since the image I am importing is `1.png`, the filename should be also starting with `1` so that the image will link from `index.html`.   However, because the generated image file in the `dist` starts with `src`, the image link breaks.

I did a lot changes in codes, to find the core of this problem, and it seems like this happens when

1. tsconfig.json compilerOptions -> "module": "esnext"
2. react-loadable is used
3. image is imported in the loaded component

If I change tsconfig.json compilerOptions -> "module": "`commonjs`", then it seems to work fine.

I would like to know if anybody has an idea why this is happening.